# In Reverso, is there a way to exclude words from being translated?

Tags: translation

I'm trying to make Reverso translate a sentence, but one of the words in the sentence should stay litterally, as it is, and not be translated (because, for instance, it is supposed to be a foreign word in this sentence, or it is a proper noun and not to be translated).
I've tried surrounding the word with special characters, like brackets or quotes, but it doesn't seem to work like that.
I don't even know if Reverso provides such a feature, or if a trick exists to simulate it.

I'm interested in the issue also in the context of the Reverso REST API.